# I need to write a query which repeats the rows by incrementing the values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with three columns say ID with identity, name and location and for this columns say I have values as

```
(1,'RAM','CA'), 
(2,'SAM','IA'),
(3,'PAM','MI')
etc....
```

Now want to get 100 rows, say after 3rd row, the 4th row should again start with same name and same location but adding one value to it, say 4th row will be values 
`(4,'RAM1','CA1'),` similarly 5th row will be `(5,'SAM1','IA1')` and 6th row will be `(6,'PAM1','MI1')`. Again for 7th row it should give values as `(7,'RAM2','CA2')` and so on. So it should continue like this till 100th row, for that I need to write the code, I could not able to figure it out, can you please help me in this.

Thanks,
Aparanjit

Comment: Do you just want to use the first 3 or n rows, or repeat all rows in the table. So if there are 5 rows, repeat the 5 rows, and 10 rows repeat the 10, and so on?

Comment: Do you want to end up with exactly 100 rows, a max `[ID]` of `100` or just more than 100 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be662/1)**

```
--Your table
create table t (id int identity(1,1), col1 varchar(10),
                                  col2 varchar(10))
--Insert query
insert into t
select c1 + case when number = 1 then '' else convert(varchar(10),number-1) end col1,
       c2 + case when number = 1 then '' else convert(varchar(10),number-1) end col2
from master..spt_values cross join 
    (values ('RAM','CA'),('SAM','IA'),('PAM','MI')) AS temp (c1,c2)
where type='p' and number between 1 and 100

--Results
|  ID |  COL1 | COL2 |
------|-------|------|--
| 1 |   RAM |   CA |
| 2 |   SAM |   IA |
| 3 |   PAM |   MI |
| 4 |  RAM1 |  CA1 |
| 5 |  SAM1 |  IA1 |
| 6 |  PAM1 |  MI1 |
| 7 |  RAM2 |  CA2 |
| 8 |  SAM2 |  IA2 |
| 9 |  PAM2 |  MI2 |
| 10 |  RAM3 |  CA3 |
| 11 |  SAM3 |  IA3 |
| 12 |  PAM3 |  MI3 |
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) You could try something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        [name] VARCHAR(20),
        location varchar(20)
)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('RAM','CA'), ('SAM','IA'), ('PAM','MI')

DECLARE @NumberOfRows INT = 100

;WITH RowIDs AS (
        SELECT  1 RowID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT RowID + 1
        FROM    RowIDs
        WHERE   RowID + 1 <= @NumberOfRows
)
, JoinIDs AS (
        SELECT  RowID,
                ((RowID - 1) % 3 + 1) JoinID
        FROM    RowIDs
)
SELECT  j.RowID,
        t.name,
        t.location

FROM    JoinIDs j INNER JOIN
        @Table t    ON  j.JoinID = t.ID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21979)